# Is it possible to draw this graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to draw a general graph with degree sequence $(4; 4; 2; 2; 3)$? Explain.

Draw a graph that has vertex set $\{A, B, C, D, E\}$ and edge set $E=\{e_1=\{A, B\}, e_2=\{A, C\}, e_3=\{D\}. e_4=\{E, B\}\}$.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

There is no graph with degree sequence $(4, 4, 2, 2, 3)$. The sum of the five degrees is 15, but since every edge contributes two to the total degrees, the sum of the degrees must be even.

For your second question, what keeps you from just drawing five vertices and the four edges? Could it be the edge $e_3$?. The most reasonable interpretation is a loop on vertex $D$, but under the standard interpretation of a graph, that's not allowed, since an edge is defined as a two-element *set* of vertices, so you'd have to say either "this isn't a graph" (so drawing it is impossible) or "we'll interpret this as what is known as a *multigraph* with a single loop" (and so you could draw it).

Comment: yes this is homework, I am struggling to draw this graph! I am not sure if it's even possible

Comment: @user88364. Draw the vertices $C, A, B, E, D$ in a row, in that order. Draw a line between $A$ and $B$. That's edge $e_1$. Do the same for edges $e_2$ and $e_4$. Draw a loop from $D$ back to itself. That's the "edge" $e_3$.